# Play Store listing achieving localisation per country rather than language

Tags: google-play

The context for my question lies in that I am building an English language app which carries info from multiple countries, including India, UK and US. Users from US typically use `en-US` as their language and that's straightforward. However, in India, about 50% people are using `en-US`, 35% `en-GB` and about 15% `en-IN`.

What I want to achieve is to place different screenshots into the Play store listing such that visitors from US will see screenshots which display the US related information, visitors from India will see the India-specific screenshots and so on.

Since there is also UK in the picture, it's pretty much not an option to place all the different screenshots - it'll get too cluttered then.

Comment: hi @trungdien. Were you able to find a solution that worked for u?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, **this is not possible**. Google only allows localization per language and not individual territories or countries.

A possible workaround would be an app onboarding with a localized introduction.

Answer (score 0):

the4kman is right - the store does not offer variation by country. But perhaps the following works for you:

Depending on your requirements, your best bet might be creating separate listings for each market (country) and using product flavors similar to creating e.g. paid and free versions of an app, except that in your case the code will probably be the same. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html for details.

You could then just use one default set of screenshots per market that is not localized and therefore does not change with language.

Just be aware that these will be like separate apps, they can coexist on a device, and they don't share local storage.